# Why do we do open loop analysis for closed loop system? Why cant we directly analyse closed loop system?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, control-system

The intention to ask this question is that, just wanted to know the reason of breaking a loop for bode plot analysis

Comment: It allows us to separate the contribution of the signal due to the input and due to the feedback loop. It simplifies mathematical analysis.

Comment: The feedback loop will give you additional poles. It's better to identify the properties of the open loop first so you can tell those poles apart from those introduced by the controller.

Comment: Stability and relative stability of the closed loop are better analysed using the open loop TF. Also, controller design is often more amenable from the root locus (a plot of the closed loop poles as a function of forward path gain).

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what is needed for a loop to become unstable ?

According to me 2 conditions need to be met for the **open** loop:

1) the phase has to turn 180 degrees, meaning the signal must invert.

2) the loop must have a gain larger than 1 at the frequency where 1) is valid. Meaning, the signal must be amplified.

Often I can easily determine if these conditions are met for a certain circuit. In practice I perform an AC (small signal) analysis on my circuit, plot the Bode diagrams and I can determine if 1) and 2 ) are met or not.

From the Bode plot I can determine the location (frequency) of the poles and zeros of the open-loop system. When the loop is closed these poles and zeros move according to certain rules. I refer to control theory for this.

Now what would these conditions turn into when the loop is closed ?

Actually I do not know. Also I have no need to know since I open the loop which gives me an insightful way of determining stability.

It is probably possible but much more complex to determine the stability of a closed loop system using poles and zeros.

I can test a closed loop in a different way though. What I then do is simulate the circuit in a transient (time) analysis and when the circuit is in a stable condition (in my simulator) I introduce a current step or voltage step and look at the response. In case of an unstable system I would see that in the response. Even an oscillation might start.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the negative feedback, which is the most common closed loop. By braking the loop you are aiming to find the open loop transfer function.
If the open loop transfer function is T(s), then when you add a negative feedback on your system, regarding the frequency domain, you are just dividing by (1+T(s)). The input-to-output transfer function will have a response in the form of T(s)/(1+T(s)), which means that you care only about stability. While all other parameters like control-to-output functions and output impendance will have response in the form F(s)/(1+T(s)) and normally you will design a compensator to make sure the 1/(1+T(s)) is limited in a certain value range.

Since all those important parameters are dependant on T(s), analysing T(s) will give you insight of basicly the whole system behaviour and stability. This is a much more general and rational method than analysing the closed-loop system without having the T(s) and analysing all transfer functions and impendances separately, even if this is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a switching power supply. The output ringing may occur at many frequencies, including LC structures downstream from the feedback node. The amateur designer easily gets confused by all the stored-energy loops, and has trouble diagnosing the primary (DC_regulation, low frequency AC regulation) behavior in the face of high frequency ringing.

The professional designer, using the real circuit, inserts massive caps and high value resistors to allow DC_feedback control *and* the injection of tiny pulses or swept-sin test signals to extract the BODE.

Why use "the real circuit"? to ensure all the parasitics are included.

NASA switching power supplies have the ability to *change* the switching frequency, to move away from spacecraft powerbus resonances. Thus NASA is extra cautious about trusting "stability" in any form.

Comment: Thanks for the info.But adding high cap to extract bode is just like breaking the loop. Is it necessary to do this to analyse bode.

Comment: *NASA switching power supplies have the ability to change the switching frequency, to move away from spacecraft powerbus resonances. Thus NASA is extra cautious about trusting "stability" in any form.* Since there will always be ripple of the switching frequency on the supply, what NASA does is smart. That way they can change the frequency and move it to a value where it is less of a problem for the circuit which runs from that supply. This by itself has **nothing** to do with making loops stable.

Comment: Actually for the Bode plot I use an "extreme" RC lowpass filter, a 100 Mohm resistor and a 1 Farad cap to ground. I insert that at a point where it will affect the circuit the least. Then I place an AC=1 voltage source after the filter. Since DC passes unharmed through filter and AC source, the DC solution of my circuit remains unaffected (check that!). Then I do an AC sweep over frequency and plot the Magnitude and Phase of the signal at the input of my RC filter. That's the open-loop Bode plot. So no swept-sine (it is a small signal analysis, there are no sinewaves) and no pulses either.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, hello, you mean you break the loop in ac but keep it closed in dc for simulation purposes or you have built some hardware in which you've tried it already?

Comment: Yes, for open loop I use AC and DC, the AC simulation **needs** a DC anyway to determine the device's operating points. For the closed loop I can only use transient for stability analysis. I can still use AC and DC for closed loop but these simulation will not prove stability. Hardware ? Yes, I have been using this method for 25 years. Many designs have been checked with this. It is standard practice. I know many fellow EEs who use the same method. Follow a course in Analog circuit design and this is what they will teach you (if the course is any good).

Comment: I see, I use a 1-kH inductance and a 1-kF capacitor to perform this trick, similar to what you did. I remember seeing this from Vince Bello, if you remember the nice fellow. He was porting average models of his own to a SPICE platform, 25 years ago : ) For hardware, this is cool, but what practical component values do you use then? Don't tell me you stack caps to meet 1 F! ^_^

Comment: I also used an inductor in the past but since sometimes having trouble with resonances of that LC I switched to using an RC. To prevent the voltage drop across the resistor I use an ideal voltage buffer after the AC filter. That way the resistor does not change the DC solution.